# What are the Red Stars for in Sonic 4: Episode 2?

Tags: sonic-the-hedgehog-4-episode-2

I got all the red stars in Sonic 4 Episode 2, but nothing happens. What are they supposed to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike the other Sonic games, in Episode 2, the Red Star Rings are mere collectibles. Collecting all of them don't unlock any special features/stage in the game, you'll only get an achievement after you collect them all and beat the boss in Death Egg mk.II Zone Act 1.

[image: Achievement]

[Source](http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Sonic_the_Hedgehog_4:_Episode_II)

Answer (score 2):

One Red Ring is hidden per act, and an achievement is unlocked after collecting them all.

http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Sonic_the_Hedgehog_4:_Episode_II